# I cannot get input to work under google app script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I'm writing a web app under google sheets and can't get an input field to work. What am I doing wrong?
everything works but uname is always empty (not undefined).

edit: I'm adding the full code after simplifying it as much as I could.
In the log I get "name" regardless of the input I type in.

In the file code.gs:

```
function doGet () {
      var participant = {};

      var templ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('out');   
      return templ.evaluate();;


}


function formSubmit(name) {

      Logger.log("name " + name);


      }
```

In out.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <base target ="_top">    
  </head>
  <body dir="rtl"; background-color: #92a8d1;>


    <label> Name 1 </label> <input type="text" id="firstname"><br>
    <label> Name 2 </label> <input type="text" id="lastname"> <br><br>
    <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>


     <script>

    document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", getData());

    function getData(){ 
      var uname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;   
      google.script.run.formSubmit(uname);


    }

      </script>





  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please share the code in it's entirety? What is `formSubmit` supposed to do?

Comment: See edits above. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the value of `<input type="text" id="firstname">` when the button is clicked.

  - In your current situation, when you see the log with the script editor, only `name` is retrieved. This is your current issue.
- You want to know the reason of the issue.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", getData());` is used. In this case, when the HTML is loaded, `getData()` is run by `()` of `getData()`. By this, `uname` becomes `""` and `""` is sent to `formSubmit(uname)`, then, when you see the log, you see `name`. And also, in this case, even when the button is clicked, `google.script.run.formSubmit(uname);` cannot be run. I think that this is the reason of the issue of your script in your question.

In order to avoid this, please modify your script as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", getData());
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", getData);
```

- By the above modification for your script, when `sample` is inputted to "Name 1" and click "Send" button, you can see `name sample` at the log with the script editor.

#### Reference:

- [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike, this was the problem. I'm not sure why the parentheses are not needed here and why the function call did work. But it does work now.

Comment: @Oren Mano Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when `()` is added to the function name and run the script, the function is run. For example, when the function is `function sample() { console.log("foo"); }`, when `sample()` is run, you can see `foo` at the console. On the other hand, when `sample` is run, you can see the script of function at the console.

Comment: @Oren Mano In the script in your question, the function `getData()` is declared at `addEventListener`, in this case, when `addEventListener` is run, the function `getData` is run. In this case, it is required to declare it as the script. So `addEventListener("click", getData())` was required to be modified to `addEventListener("click", getData)`. By this, when the event is run, the function `getData` is run with the arguments. If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example form that you can probably use to accomplish your needs.  This form is used as a simple receipt collection system.  You can actually take and upload images from a mobile device with it.  I also has text and button input types and upload a form node.

Code.gs

```
var receiptImageFolderId='';
var SSID='';

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Receipt Collection')
    .addItem('Run as Dialog', 'showAsDialog')
    .addItem('Run as Sidebar', 'showAsSidebar')
    .addToUi();
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1).activate();
}

function uploadTheForm(theForm) {
  var rObj={};
  rObj['vendor']=theForm.vendor;
  rObj['amount']=theForm.amount;
  rObj['date']=theForm.date;
  rObj['notes']=theForm.notes
  var fileBlob=theForm.receipt;
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(receiptImageFolderId);
  rObj['file']=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  rObj['filetype']=fileBlob.getContentType(); 
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rObj));
  var cObj=formatFileName(rObj);
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(cObj));
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(SSID);
  ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').appendRow([cObj.date,cObj.vendor,cObj.amount,cObj.notes,cObj.file.getUrl()]);
  var html=Utilities.formatString('<br />FileName: %s',cObj.file.getName());
  return html;
}

function formatFileName(rObj) {
  if(rObj) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(rObj));
    var mA=rObj.date.split('-');
    var name=Utilities.formatString('%s_%s_%s.%s',Utilities.formatDate(new Date(mA[0],mA[1]-1,mA[2]),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"yyyyMMdd"),rObj.vendor,rObj.amount,rObj.filetype.split('/')[1]);
    rObj.file.setName(name);
  }else{
      throw('Invalid or No File in formatFileName() upload.gs');
  }
  return rObj;
}

function doGet() {
  var output=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('receipts').setTitle('thehtml');
  return output.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=360, initial-scale=1');
}

function showAsDialog() {
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('thehtml');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'Receipts')
}

function showAsSidebar() {
   var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('thehtml');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}

function initForm() {
  var datestring=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd")
  return {date:datestring};
}
```

The Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(rObj){
          $('#dt').val(rObj.date);
        })
        .initForm();

      });
      function fileUploadJs(frmData) {
        var amt=$('#amt').val();
        var vndr=$('#vndr').val();
        var img=$('#img').val();
        if(!amt){
          window.alert('No amount provided');
          $('#amt').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!vndr) {
          window.alert('No vendor provided');
          $('#vndr').focus();
          return;
        }
        if(!img) {
          window.alert('No image chosen');
          $('#img').focus();
        }
        document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
        google.script.run
        .withSuccessHandler(function(hl){
          document.getElementById('status').innerHTML=hl;
        })
        .uploadTheForm(frmData)
      }
      console.log('My Code');
    </script>
    <style>
      input,textarea{margin:5px 5px 5px 0;}
    </style>
  </head>
   <body>
    <h3 id="main-heading">Receipt Information</h3>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <br /><input type="date" name="date" id="dt"/>
        <br /><input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Amount" id="amt" />
        <br /><input type="text" name="vendor" placeholder="Vendor" id="vndr"/>
        <br /><textarea name="notes" cols="40" rows="2" placeholder="NOTES"></textarea>
        <br/>Receipt Image
        <br /><input type="file" name="receipt" id="img" />
        <br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what the dialog looks like:

[image]